# Conditionally assign array indices

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to be able to create separate instances of an array depending on some conditional.

I know I can use the spread operator in tandem with a boolean to do the following.

```
const arr = ['foo', 
             'bar',
              ...(conditional ? ['fizz'] : []),
              ...(conditional ? ['buzz'] : [])
            ];
```

My question is if this method is preferred or if it's better to just conditionally create separate instances of the array.. I.e.

```
let arr = [];
if (conditional) {
    arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'];
} else {
    arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
}
```

**The order of the elements in the array does matter. An so I cannot simply assign `foo, bar` and then conditionally push on `fizz, buzz`** I.e. I may want my array to be like

```
const arr = ['foo',
             ...(conditional ? ['bar'] : []),
             'fizz',
             ...(conditional ? ['buzz'] : [])
            ];
```

Any cool ideas?

Comment: First of all, you should simplify to `...(conditional ? ['fizz', 'buzz'] : [])` - unless they are different `conditional` expressions?

Comment: "*so I cannot simply assign `foo, bar` and then conditionally push on `fizz, buzz`*" - what makes you think that? Surely `push` does respect order…

Comment: I added some more explanation. Hopefully that makes more sense about what I mean about having control of the array order.

They are all going to be the same conditional. What's your recommendation on simplifying that more?

Comment: No, I still don't understand why you couldn't achieve the same result with  `const arr = ['foo', 'bar']; if (conditional) arr.push('fizz', 'buzz');` And all the examples you gave until now don't put an element at a specific index, but just append it in the end.

Comment: The result of this array is going to be fed into the exceljs library to create spreadsheets. The contents of the array correspond to rows in the spreadsheet and they have to be of a specific template order. It's hard to explain in words

Comment: Then explain in code, and use a non-trivial example?

Comment: I'm saying I need my indices to be in a specific sequence depending on a conditional. Push would simply push all elements to the end of the array. See section 3.1 https://2ality.com/2017/04/conditional-literal-entries.html

Comment: Well the example in there has non-conditional elements after the conditional ones, and needs to be handled differently than the examples you've given so far. Is that what you are actually after? Then please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach the problem from the other end. Use the conditional to remove items.

```
let arr = ["foo","bar","tax","lax","fiz","buz"];

if (!condition)
{
   arr.splice(arr.indexOf("tax"),1); // removes the item by name
   arr.splice(4,1); // removes the item by position
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to insert elements at specified positions:

```
let arr = ["first", "third"]
if (condition)
{
    arr.splice(1,0,"second");
    arr.splice(3,0,"fourth");
}
```

I would prefer not using "smart" syntactic sugars. IMO they affect code readability which does no good in the long run.

Comment: I hear ya about not using syntactic sugars haha. But not sure if I want to use splice to hardcode the indices either. It's certainly a valid solution though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
const arr = [];
arr.push('foo', 'bar');
if (conditional) arr.push('fizz', 'buzz');
… // continue with conditional or non-conditional sections
```

or respectively:

```
const arr = [];
arr.push('foo');
if (conditional) arr.push('bar');
arr.push('fizz')
if (conditional) arr.push('buzz');
```

Comment: Please see my updated example. Sorry for the confusion, but any alternatives given what I now have?

Comment: @user2402616 My answer doesn't really change, but I've incorporated the new example